# Using Who versus that in a sentence

Tags: grammar, questions

In this sentence:

> We are asking you to invite your congregation that have a passion for mission to consider volunteering three hours one day a week.

Should it read "who" or "that" after "congregation"? I always used "who" but was told that "who" only goes with proper nouns.

Comment: Whoever told you that _who_ only goes with proper nouns was talking nonsense. As John and Barrie say, _who_ tends to go with nouns denoting people, but that is not absolute.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence probably doesn't mean what you intend. The invitation is to the congregation as a whole, if the whole congregation has a passion for mission.  If that is your intent, you should use "that" since "congregation" is not a person but a large group.

However, if you intended what I think you intended:

> We are asking you to invite your congregation's members who have a passion for mission...

In this case "who" would be correct.

The rule is "who" for people, "that" for things, though the rule is in practice a little soft.

Comment: Right. Or _the members of your congregation who_; and it doesn't matter whether you use _who have_ or _that have_. They're the same and they're both grammatically correct; which one you use is up to you.

Comment: Yes. _That_ can have a human antecedent when it introduces a defining relative clause.